# How to use DEFINE() in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel

I have code in const.php:

```
define('COLORS',array('black','red','white'));
```

In page add.blade.php:

```
<select  id="example-multiple-selected" multiple="multiple" name="ProductColor[]" >
 <?php foreach (COLORS as $colorKey => $colorName) :?>
  <option value="{{$colorKey}}"
     @if (old("ProductColor"))
       {{ (in_array($colorKey, old("ProductColor")) ? "selected":"") }}
     @endif>{{$colorName}}</option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

//example (get 2 value ('red','white')

Then, in the page controller, I add it to the database:

```
$color = implode(',',$products->color);
```

//save in DB (1,2)

I display it:

```
@foreach(COLORS as $colorKey => $colorName)
  @if($product->color == $colorKey) {{$colorName}}
  @endif
 @endforeach
```

//only display is: red

Comment: The problem is not the define. it's that you are not normalising your data. Don't do `implode` store each key in a separate row in a related table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

you change file composer.json

and add index files in autoload

sample :

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers/constants.php"
        ]
    },
```

and run command in project path :

```
composer dump-autoload
```